# My login page always shows that data is incorrect. Cant find the bug

Tags: php, authentication

Here's my code:

```
<?php

try {
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tp1-2015_groep2", "utp1-2015_groep2", "bB5HvUC7MV7mqpWp");
$connection->query("SET NAMES utf8");
    echo "<p id='popupg'>Heeft u al een account? U kunt nu inloggen!</p>";
} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    echo "<p id='popupr'>U bent NIET verbonden! Probeer alstublieft opnieuw te verbinden!</p>";
    exit;
}



function hashedPassword($username, $password) {
    return hash ("sha512", $username.$password);
}


//zodra het login knop ingedrukt wordt..
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    //Verkrijg de info binnen van onze formulier
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Haal de geselecteerde velden op
    $sql = $connection->prepare ("SELECT id, username, password FROM gebruikersgegevens WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");


    $passwordHash = hashedPassword($username, $password);

    //Koppel de onderstaande waarden aan elkaar
    $sql->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //Voer het voorbereidde query uit
    $sql->execute();
    if ($sql->execute()) {

    //Haal rij op..
    $sql->fetch();

    //kijken of de rijen kloppen..
    $count = $sql->rowCount();

            if ($count !== 0) {

        //Zodra count "true" geeft, vergelijk wachtwoorden..
            $validPassword = password_verify($password, $user['password']);
                if ($validPassword) {
                    //Bied de gebruiker een login sessie aan.
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
                        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                            //Stuurt de gebruiker door naar het onderstaande link..        
                            header('Location: index.php');
                            exit;
                    } else {
                        die('<p id="popupr">Het verifiëren is fout gegaan!</p>');
                }

        } else {
            //een tijdelijke error oplossing!
            echo '<p id="popupr">De combinatie van wachtwoord en gebruikersnaam klopt niet!</p>';

        }
    }
}
```

I have to make a blog for school where you need to be able to register and login. 
But the login page doesn't really work. 
Can't find the bug. 
I tried so many things, but nothing worked.
It always says the combination to login is wrong.
I already think where it goes wrong, but I can't find what's wrong. It's where the password is getting verified.

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**. Please read [How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need more information - what is the purpose of the code? What is your expected output? What is the *actual* output?

Comment: Why are you checking the database for the username and password combination and then checking in your code if they match. You already verified they match by having a result from your query.

Comment: Okay, how should I change it in my code? I'm a beginner and don't know what is should do now....

Comment: Remove the `//Zodra count "true" geeft, vergelijk wachtwoorden..`  - bit and set the session when you have `$count > 0`

Comment: Okay that works, but which session should I use? The ones I got doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have `session_start();` in your PHP file. You need this at the top of every page that uses sessions.

Comment: @Eenhoorn_Bullitz I've added an answer with the rewritten code and explaining some things you did wrong. If it helps make sure to give it an upvote. Dank!

Comment: @Kalkran, the 'session_start();' is in my template.php, whats included in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing double work. For one you're retrieving rows from the table which match both the `username` and `password` and then later you're comparing the password which is hashed using a different hashing method to the hashed password. Later you're accessing `$user` which hasn't been set yet (You're using `$sql->fetch()` without assigning the result into a variable).

You also had a double `$sql->execute()`. Which (if it returns false) means something went wrong with the query, not that there aren't any rows.

Try the following,

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    //Verkrijg de info binnen van onze formulier
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Haal de geselecteerde velden op
    $sql = $connection->prepare ("SELECT id, username, password FROM gebruikersgegevens WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");


    $passwordHash = hashedPassword($username, $password);

    //Koppel de onderstaande waarden aan elkaar
    $sql->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //Voer het voorbereidde query uit
    if ($sql->execute()) {

        //Haal rij op.. (En sla op in $user)
        $user = $sql->fetch();

        //kijken of de rijen kloppen..
        $count = $sql->rowCount();

        if ($count > 0) {

            //Bied de gebruiker een login sessie aan.
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

            //Stuurt de gebruiker door naar het onderstaande link..        
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;

        } else {
            die('<p id="popupr">Het verifiëren is fout gegaan!</p>');
        }

    } else {
        //een tijdelijke error oplossing!
        // Je komt alleen hier als de query mislukt is (fout in de query of database).
        echo '<p id="popupr">De combinatie van wachtwoord en gebruikersnaam klopt niet!</p>';

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You use `password_verify()` to verifiy password but you generate hash with `hash()` function. Try to change `hash()` to `password_hash()`. See [password_verify() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). `password_hash()` using `crypt()` to generate password see [password_hash documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: Okay I tried, but then I got this error: Warning: password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\Users\lesley\Documents\lesley\blog\login.php on line 21

Comment: Can you maybe put it in the code? I'm actually a beginner and I don't understand it well.... XD